# Why Wordpress ajax does not work in mobile browser?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When I just open the link by computer it works fine when you click on each days, but the same thing does not work in mobile browser.

```
function total_lunch_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('script-name', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('script-name', 'MyAjax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'security' => wp_create_nonce('my-special-string')
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'total_lunch_scripts');

function lunch_action_callback(){
    check_ajax_referer('my-special-string', 'security');
    $date = $_POST['today_date'];
    lunch_front_today($date);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_lunch_action', 'lunch_action_callback');
```

https://dev.totalmedia.nu/total_lunch/total-lunch/

Comment: Loading fine on iOS for me.

Comment: Thanks so the problem is with Android

Comment: You tell me, you're the one reporting it. You said it doesn't work in mobile browsers, I'm not finding that's true. What device are you using? What browser?

Comment: Chrome , Firefox in Galaxies I tried but doesn't worked

Comment: Then start using https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Thanks I will try and say my results here